# Import Wizard only partially uploads csv table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm relatively new to MySQL

I am trying to import a csv table with 25,000 rows and 37 variables into MySQL using the import wizard. The import wizard uploads successfully but only 2483 rows appear. How do I upload the entire csv file?

Comment: Have you checked record 2484 in the file to see if it has anything different that could be causing the import process to stop?

Comment: yes, I also tried uploading the file multiple times in different databases. It appears that the 2483rd row is just like any other row.

Comment: Did you mean 2484 instead of 2483?

Comment: No, I have uploaded the table multiple times, and it seems to only capture between 2400 and 2600 rows. In my most recent attempt only 2508 rows successfully uploaded.

Comment: What tool are you using to do the upload? Also you should have got some error on screen or in a log file. Can you check for that too?

Comment: I'm using the data import wizard to upload a csv file. When I look at the message log during the upload all I see is prepare import, data import (a lot of times), and import data file finished.

Answer (score 0):

Please use load file:
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.CSV' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;

Other option USE "LOCAL":

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.CSV' INTO TABLE tbl_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;

If LOCAL is specified, the file is read by the client program on the client host and sent to the server. The file can be given as a full path name to specify its exact location. If given as a relative path name, the name is interpreted relative to the directory in which the client program was started.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately no luck, I also tried LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, and got an error message: Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Answer (score 0):

I was able to upload the entire csv file by deleting a few columns. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You may use SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv"; to see the directory that has been configured.

You have two options:

Move your file to the directory specified by secure-file-priv.

Disable secure-file-priv. This must be removed from startup and cannot be modified dynamically. To do this check your MySQL start up parameters (depending on platform) and mysql.cnf